# How to fix the order of scale in rCharts nPlot?

Tags: visualization, rstudio, rcharts

Currently I've got a data set look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Time = c("2013-07", "2013-07", "2013-07","2013-10", "2014-01", "2014-05",  "2014-05", "2014-05"),
                 local = "ABC",
                 Point = c("Point1", "Point2", "Point3", "Point3", "Point3", "Point1", "Point2", "Point3"),
                 Part1 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 1, NaN),
                 Part2 = c(NaN, 2, 11, 4, 2, NaN, 1, 1),
                 Part3 = c(4, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 1, NaN))
```

I'm trying to plot a bar plot using rCharts in R studio.

```
n1 <- nPlot(Part2 ~ Time, group = "Point", data = df, type = "multiBarChart")
n1
```

The output looks like what I want except one thing.

Ideally the order of x axis should be 2013-07, 2013-10, 2014-01, 2014-05

But the one I got is 2013-07, 2014-05, 2013-10, 2014-01.

I have also tried to convert "Time" variable into a Date format or a POSIXct format. Things turn out to be the same.

So can anybody help me with this?

Is there any help file for rCharts with all possible functions, arguments and customization explanations?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the primary issue is missing data, which `nvd3` does not like.  I changed the structure of the data slightly with `expand.grid` to make sure that there as a point for each date, and in that case `nvd3` sorts as expected whether we hand it a number or character date.

Here is the code

```
library(rCharts)

df <- data.frame(Time = c("2013-07", "2013-07", "2013-07","2013-10", "2014-01", "2014-05",  "2014-05", "2014-05"),
                 local = "ABC",
                 Point = c("Point1", "Point2", "Point3", "Point3", "Point3", "Point1", "Point2", "Point3"),
                 Part1 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 1, NaN),
                 Part2 = c(NaN, 2, 11, 4, 2, NaN, 1, 1),
                 Part3 = c(4, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 1, NaN))   

#df$Time <- as.Date( paste0(as.character(df$Time),"-01" ) )


df2 <- merge(
  structure(expand.grid(unique(df$Time),unique(df$Point)),names=c("Time","Point"))
  ,df
  ,all=T
)
#df2[,4:6] <- lapply(df2[,4:6], function(x){ ifelse(is.na(x),0,x) })



n1 <- nPlot(Part2 ~ Time, group = "Point", data = df2, type = "multiBarChart")
n1$xAxis (
  #"#! function(d){ return d3.time.format('%Y-%m')(new Date( d*60*60*24*1000 ) ) } !#"
  "#! function(d){ return d3.time.format('%Y-%m')(function(d){ return d3.time.format('%Y-%m')(d3.time.format('%Y-%m').parse(d) ) }) } !#"
)
n1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the plot looks great now. By the way do you know where to find a detailed documentation of how to use rCharts? For example how to customize "n1" above? I know there are something like xAxis, yAxis. What about the others and what can I do inside xAxis, yAxis etc.?

Comment: documentation will be our next focus.  nvd3 is particularly difficult since it is not well documented itself, but here is a prototype set of docs for rCharts http://timelyportfolio.github.io/docs/_build/html/

Comment: Thanks I'd take a good look at this. rCharts is quite interesting.